# C++ How do I access and modify an array with using []?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

For an assignment, I have take a class with a first and last name (string) and reverse the order, one method using array notation[] and it accepts an *char varible[]*, and another method that does the same thing, but without using any bracket notation ie[] and accepts a char *varible. I don't know any other way to reference a certain character in the list without using [] and only using pointer method. How would I go about starting the pointer method, I already finished the array method? main.cpp supplied below for context.

I know that an array is essentially a block of memory that is the data type size multiplied by how many containers you specify. Is there a way to traverse an array using the bit location in the memory allocated for the array?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Name
{
 public:
 string TheName;
 Name() { TheName=""; }
 Name(string name) { TheName=name; }
 string ReverseUsingString();
 void ReverseUsingArray(char Reversed[]);
 void ReverseUsingPtrs(char *Reversed);
 void operator =(char *name) {TheName=name;}
};
#include "NameClassImplementation.cpp" // You supply this file!
int main()
{
 Name Names[5]; Names[0] = "Ben Dover";
 Names[1] = "Chuck Roast"; Names[2] = "Jim Naysium";
 Names[3] = "Ella Quint"; Names[4] = "Justin Case";
 char reversedname1[100], reversedname2[100];

 for (int i=0; i<5; ++i)
 {
 Names[i].ReverseUsingArray(reversedname1);
 Names[i].ReverseUsingPtrs(reversedname2);
 cout << "Original Name : " << Names[i].TheName << endl;
 cout << " reversed with arrays: -->" << reversedname1 << "<--\n";
 cout << " reversed with ptrs : -->" << reversedname2 << "<--\n";
 cout << " reversed with string: -->"
 << Names[i].ReverseUsingString() << "<--\n\n";
 }
 system("pause"); return 0;
}
```

Comment: `ReverseUsingArray` and `ReverseUsingPtrs` have the identical parameter list. If you put an array declarator in a parameter list, it gets *adjusted* to be a pointer.

Comment: Right, but what has me stumped is that my professor wants us not to us brackets anywhere in the ReverseUsingPtrs, and only brackets in ReverseUsingArray, and I don't know how to manipulate the data in the array pointer without using any brackets.

Comment: `x[y]` is exactly the same as `*(x + (y))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is some example code that may be able to guide you in completing your task.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    //  create an array
    int x[1] = {1}; 

    //  create a pointer that points to an adress of particular element of aforementioned array
    int *a = x+0;

    //  modify array
    *a = 3;

    //  access element of array
    std::cout<<*a;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you so much!